# How to deploy a j2ee WAR file on DirectAdmin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-deployment, directadmin

I have build a small j2ee web application and successfully deployed the WAR file on Tomcat on my Linux (CentOS). I decided to install DirectAmdin to configure my domain and DNS.

Now, I want to deploy my WAR file on DirectAdmin. I can't find how to do this. I have installed Tomcat and deployed my project on /var/lib/tomcat/webapps folder, but when I try to connect my website on port 8080, nothing appears.

I have found [this](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=2227) tutorial for deploying a j2ee web application on DirectAdmin, but it is quite old and somehow confusing. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Requests for tutorials are off-topic here. Can you expand your question to show what you have done and what you are stuck on? That would then be an answerable question.

Comment: Thank you halfer, I have changed the question to specify where I am stuck on. Hoping this change removes my questions from off-topic ones.